# How to keep files from previous Docker stage

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, bitbucket

I have two dockerfiles that I use to build a docker image that's deployed as a AWS Lambda. and I would like to retain the files from docker image amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.9 in my final built docker image. I build the public docker image and publish it on docker hub.

**When I build this docker image locally everything is as expected.**

**However, when I use Bitbucket pipelines to build my private dockerfile pulling from my public docker image, many of the essential files are missing in the final build step.**

I need the entire /var folder from amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.9 as aws to be in my final docker image. How can I achieve this?

Public docker image:

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.9 as aws

ENV PATH=/var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/bin
ENV LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR=/var/runtime
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV TZ=:/etc/localtime
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lang/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib64:/var/runtime:/var/runtime/lib:/var/task:/var/task/lib:/opt/lib
ENV LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT=/var/task
ENV LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR=/var/runtime

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum -y install tesseract poppler-utils
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip 
RUN pip3 install pillow pytesseract requests boto3 python-dotenv pytz gql[all] PyMuPDF google-cloud-storage pdf2image --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}




ENTRYPOINT [ "/lambda-entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Private docker image:

```
FROM private-docker-image:latest

ENV PATH=/var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/bin
ENV LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR=/var/runtime
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV TZ=:/etc/localtime
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lang/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib64:/var/runtime:/var/runtime/lib:/var/task:/var/task/lib:/opt/lib
ENV LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT=/var/task
ENV LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR=/var/runtime
COPY --from=amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.9 / /
COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN chmod -R +rwx ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN chmod +x /lambda-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "start.sh" ]
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

Comment: Just to add- when I build this locally it's fine, it's only when I build it in Bitbucket pipelines that files go missing.

Comment: You can't just `COPY` the entire root filesystem from one image to another like that.  The two filesystems will overwrite each other and you're likely to have problems.  Is there a more controlled part of the image you can copy?  It looks like you `COPY --from=` Amazon's base Lambda image and not something you built yourself; how is the "public Dockerfile" used?

Comment: That ```copy / /``` was a last ditch attempt to restore the lost files. I must be missing something fundamental about docker because I can't understand why the files go missing.